# Access JIRA on HTTPS Server Using API

Tags: java, selenium, jira-rest-api, jira-rest-java-api

I am trying to access JIRA (Hosted on HTTPS server, JIRA URL Starts with HTTPS) but it is throwing an Error message .
--javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: General SSLEngine problem

I am using `AsynchronousJiraRestClientFactory().createwithBasicHttpAuthentication(uri,u`username,password)

Please help me getting through this issue , i want to access a prject location in JIRA and drop a bug into it.

Normally in Local machine , self installed Jira Work Fine with This Code as it has no Https Url.

Do i need Some Certificates  for that , if yes ..who provides them and how i have to use them in the Code.

Comment: Can you provided the full stack trace of the error message?

Comment: this is the only message shown in the console

Comment: How is this related to selenium?

Comment: looks like the provided TLS certificate or the root CA of the certificate is unknown or invalid to your JVM. It is a self signed certificate?